# Refreshing single PivotTable only

Tags: vba, pivot-table, partial-page-refresh

In Excel 2013 I have two pivot tables named "A" and "B". I need to refresh only one pivot table ("B") on sheet of my workbook for comparison.

I tried all below and it looks as if it should work as required - yet none of them will (i.e. both pivots will refresh after running any of the solutions).  I tried changing Pivot Table Data options to all possible combinations with no change to outcome.

```
Sub refresh_pivot1() 

'=================================================
Windows("File.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("Pivots").Select
'=================================================
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("B").PivotCache.Refresh
'=================================================
Worksheets("Pivots").PivotTables("B").RefreshTable
'==================================================

Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable            

For Each PvtTbl In Worksheets("Pivots").PivotTables            

    If PvtTbl = "B" Then                                            
        PvtTbl.RefreshTable          
    End If             

Next

'=================================================          
Range("G3:K12").Calculate             
'=================================================           
Dim pt As PivotTable             
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("B")           
pt.RefreshTable            
'=================================================

End Sub
```

Comment: was meant to say "none of them will" of course :)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both PivotTables are based on the same data source, then they share what's called a *PivotCache*. When you refresh a PivotTable, you are in fact refreshing the underlying PivotCache, and not an individual PivotTable. This means that when you refresh *one* PivotTable, you are actually refeshing *all' PivotTables that share that cache.

You need to tell Excel to assign your second PivotTable to a different Cache. See http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot11.html for code on how to do this (particularly the section "Create New Pivot Cache for Selected Pivot Table") or give Google a spin.

Comment: Worth also noting the significance of the query Excel asks when the second PivoTable is created from the original data sorce, in terms of sharing the same PivotCache or not.